# Example of a bialgebra which is Frobenius but not Hopf

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, hopf-algebras

Let $\Bbbk$ be a field. A well-known result (see [Larson, Sweedler, *An Associative Orthogonal Bilinear Form for Hopf Algebras*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373270?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) and [Pareigis, *When Hopf algebras are Frobenius algebras*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869371901414?via%3Dihub)) states that a bialgebra $B$ over $\Bbbk$ is a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra if and only if it is Frobenius as an algebra and the Frobenius morphism $\psi:B\to\Bbbk$ is a (left) integral on $B$ (i.e. $\sum b_1\psi(b_2)=\psi(b)1_B$ for all $b\in B$).

For didactical reasons, I would like to have an example of a (necessarily finite-dimensional) bialgebra $B$ which is Frobenius as an algebra but that is not a Hopf algebra. However, I didn't manage to construct one. Does anybody know one? Even a non-elementary one would be fine.

Alternatively, if somebody knows a proof of the fact that a Frobenius bialgebra is automatically a Hopf algebra, without further assumptions on the Frobenius homomorphism, then I would be very glad to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. Take k a field and S the multiplicative semigroup {0,1}. For notational convenience denote it S={1,x}. Consider B=k[S] the semigroup algebra.

B is bialgebra and not Hopf because S is a semigroup and nota a group.

$B\cong k[x]/(x^2-x)\cong k\times k$ is semisimple. In particular is a Frobenius algebra.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice example. For personal future reference, an explicit Frobenius coordinate system is given by $e= 1\otimes 1 - 1\otimes x - x\otimes 1$ and $\psi:B\to\Bbbk: 1\mapsto 0, x\mapsto -1$.

Comment: @EnderWiggins Unfortunately, this example doesn't work: $k[S]$ is isomorphic as an algebra to the group algebra $k[C_2]$, which is a Hopf algebra.  I think $k[x]/(x^2)$ is a counterexample to the converse, but I'm not completely certain.

Comment: @KyleMiller Maybe I am missing your point. $k[S]$ could be isomorphic to $k[C_2]$ as an algebra, but not as a bialgebra. I imagine your are considering the algebra isomorphism $$k[X]/(X^2-X) \to k[X]/(X^2-1), \quad x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(1-x),$$ which however does not preserve the comultiplication. Thus, this is not contradicting the fact that $k[S]$ as a group-like bialgebra is Frobenius but not Hopf.

Comment: @EnderWiggins I thought what you were asking is what is a Frobenius algebra that as an algebra does not extend to a Hopf algebra (at least, this is what I want to know). I missed that in your question that the iff is quantified over "$B$ is a bialgebra", sorry!

Comment: @KyleMiller No problem, good that we clarified. Btw, if your are looking for a Frobenius algebra which cannot be Hopf, than $2\times 2$ matrices over any field should do ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ussually finite dimension is part of the definition of a Frobenius algebra. So, what definition of "Frobenius" algebra do you have in mind?

In wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra#Category-theoretical_definition) a categorical definition is given. If you take a "Frobenius object" in the category of vector spaces, then Frobenius impies finite dimensionality.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why I stressed finite-dimensional: I was trying to avoid un-helpful (non-)answers because I would like to see a genuine, ring-theoretic example of a bialgebra over a field that (as an algebra) is Frobenius (Casimir+Frobenius morphism or non-degenerate bilinear associative form, choose the description you prefer)

Comment: Just to be sure, when I read your post I thought of an infinite dimensional example, but now I read carefully and I see that what you wrote is "necessarily finite dimensional". But then, what's wrong with Larson-Sweedler-Pareigis result? You are lookin for finite or infinite dimensional examples?

Comment: Since the additional condition on the Frobenius morphism is required to have a Hopf algebra structure, I would like to see an example of a bialgebra which is Frobenius but doesn't satisfy that condition, so that it is not a Hopf algebra. In particular, being Frobenius, it has to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: I think you misunderstood  the statement. Larson-Sweedler proves that a finitely generated bialgebra over a p.i. ring, (e.g. a finite dimensional bialgebra over a field) a Frobenius structure provides an atipode (and viceversa). So, if a finite dimensional bialgebra $B$ is Frobenius as algebra, then it is necesarily Hopf.

Comment: Where did they prove this? In their renowned paper _An Associative Orthogonal Bilinear Form for Hopf Algebras_ they only prove that a Hopf algebra $H$ over a PID is Frobenius. And in fact the Frobenius morphism that comes out of their construction is an integral on $H$. Later Pareigis proved that over any commutative ring $\Bbbk$ a bialgebra B is an fgp Hopf algebra with $\int B^*\cong \Bbbk$ if and only if it is Frobenius and the Frobenius homomorphism is an integral on $B$. But I am completely not aware of a result saying that a fd bialgebra is Hopf iff it is Frobenius..

Comment: a field is a p.i.d. so I don't see the problem

Comment: I am missing the converse: why a bialgebra which is Frobenius as an algebra should admit an antipode? Larson-Sweedler proved only one implication, from Hopf to Frobenius. Pareigis proved the converse, but under the additional assumption that the Frobenius morphism is an integral. I would like to see a proof of $B$ Frobenius $\Rightarrow$ $B$ fd Hopf or a counterexample of a Frobenius bialgebra which is not Hopf